# Grep pattern including dashes and restricting to a filename extension

Tags: grep

I am trying to use grep to find some tex files containing the pattern `->-`:

```
grep -R -- "->-" *.tex
```

But this doesn't work. If I do:

```
grep -R -- "->-"
```

instead, it works, but is really slow and gives me clearly not only tex files but also matches lots of other file (for example binary files).

What would be the fastest way to do this search?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `-R` tells `grep` to recursively search through all files in the directory. So, you can't combine it with a specific group of files. Therefore, you can either use `find` [as suggested by @KM.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/185954/), or shell globbing:

```
$ shopt -s globstar
$ grep -- "->-" **/*.tex
```

The `shopt` command activates bash's globstar feature:

```
globstar
                  If set, the pattern ** used in a pathname expansion con‐
                  text will match all files and zero or  more  directories
                  and  subdirectories.  If the pattern is followed by a /,
                  only directories and subdirectories match.
```

You then give `**/*.tex` as a pattern and that will match all `.tex` files in the current directory and any subdirectories.

If you're using `zsh`, there's no need for the `shopt` (which is a bash feature anyway) since `zsh` can do this by default.

Comment: Since I am using `zsh` this seems to be the easiest syntax and it also works fast enough for me.

Answer (score 7):

Try `find` and `grep` instead, with `-exec`:

```
find path_to_tex_files_directory -name "*.tex" -exec grep -- "->-" {} \;
```

or with `xargs`

```
find path_to_tex_files_directory -name "*.tex" | xargs grep -- "->-"
```

Comment: [GNU find](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Multiple-Files.html) also let's you use `-exec grep -- "->-" {} +` in order to run grep on multiple files at a time. And when it's combined with [GNU xargs](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/xargs-options.html), `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...` can be used, so that tricky filenames don't cause any issues.

Answer (score 3):

If your `grep` supports it<sup>1</sup>, you could use the `--include` switch:

```
grep -R --include '*.tex' -- "->-"
```

or

```
grep -R --include='*.tex' -- "->-"
```

---

1:
Available at least in GNU `grep`:

```
--include=GLOB
        Search only files whose base name matches GLOB
```

and OSX `grep`:

```
--include
        If specified, only files matching the given filename pattern are searched.
```

Answer (score 2):

`-R` option stand for recursive, I guess you have no dir in pattern *.tex.

maybe try something like:

```
find . -name \*.tex -exec grep -l -- "->-" {} \;
```

- you can drop `-l` option, if you don't care about filename
- if you want to see filename and pattern:

  ```
  find . -name \*.tex -exec grep -l -- "->-" {} \; | xargs grep -- "->-"
  ```

  but that's a double grep, @KM solution seems better..